Getting Value Error while running the model prediction when it is deployed to Google Cloud Run
I'm getting the following error while running the model prediction through my streamlit app deployed on Google Cloud Run. But the same code is running perfectly locally and on Google colab with same python version(3.10). The only difference is tensorflow version the deployed version using 2.14 whereas on the local machine I'm using 2.15.
But I don't see major changes in both versions of tensorflow that would affect the normal prediction code.
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 3962112 elements to shape [67,77,16,16] (1320704 elements) for '{{node Reshape_2}} = Reshape[T=DT_INT64, Tshape=DT_INT32](ArgMax, Reshape_2/shape)' with input shapes: [15477,16,16], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [67,77,16,16].
Traceback:
File "/home/otbuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/exec_code.py", line 85, in exec_func_with_error_handling
    result = func()
File "/home/otbuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 576, in code_to_exec
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/pages/9-Performing-like-an-algorithm.py", line 419, in <module>
    a_r, predicted_array = prediction(imagepath+inputimage, modelpath+model)
File "/app/otbtf/unet_helper.py", line 208, in prediction
    segmentation_patches = tf.reshape(
File "/opt/otbtf/lib/python3/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/opt/otbtf/lib/python3/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1021, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(e.message)

Please help me how to solve this error.
Sample code:
import tensorflow as tf

def tile_image(image_shape, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH):
    """
    Simulates the tiling process of an image into patches.
    """
    height, width = image_shape[:2]

    # Calculate the number of patches along height and width
    nrows = tf.math.ceil(height / PATCH_HEIGHT)
    ncols = tf.math.ceil(width / PATCH_WIDTH)

    # Calculate the total number of patches
    num_patches = nrows * ncols

    # Create a dummy tensor to simulate model output logits
    logits = tf.random.uniform((num_patches, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH), dtype=tf.float32)

    return logits, nrows, ncols

def prediction(image_shape, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH):
    """
    Simulates the prediction process including reshaping the output patches.
    """
    logits, nrows, ncols = tile_image(image_shape, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH)

    try:
        # Attempt to reshape logits to match the original image tiling structure
        segmentation_patches = tf.reshape(
            logits, [nrows, ncols, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH]
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        segmentation_patches = None

    return segmentation_patches

# Example function call using dynamic input shape
# Assuming an input image shape that could cause a reshaping issue
test_image_shape = (5159, 5159, 8)  # Example input image dimensions (height, width, channels)
PATCH_HEIGHT = 16  # Example patch height
PATCH_WIDTH = 16  # Example patch width

# Run the prediction function
prediction(test_image_shape, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH)


The core issue is that the number of elements in the tensor doesn't match the target shape when you try to reshape it. Make sure the shape you're reshaping to ([nrows, ncols, PATCH_HEIGHT, PATCH_WIDTH]) is compatible with the number of elements in the logits tensor.  I was successfully able to reproduce the issue by typecasting nrows and ncols to int32 before multiplication, ensuring compatibility with the expected integer input. Please refer this gist for your reference.
